# unable to add package in yarn workspace monorepo

Tags: yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am trying to import components in a shared package in a monorepo, but am unable to do so.

I have the following package.json files under the root of a repo that I want to run as a monorepo. /apps/billing is a create-react-app. /apps/shared is going to contain components for billing and other apps.

/package.json

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "billing": "cd apps/billing; yarn start"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

/apps/billing/package.json

```
{
  "name": "@root/billing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    <snip>
  },
}
```

/apps/billing/shared.json

```
{
  "name": "@root/shared",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

In the /apps/billing directory I tried to run `yarn add @root/shared` and get the following output:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@root%2fshared: Not found".
```

In billing, when I try to import a component from shared

```
import Button from '@root/shared/components/Button';
```

I get
`Module not found: Can't resolve '@root/shared/components/Button'`

Are there additional steps to setup a yarn monorepo?

Comment: try to change your registry i had a same error with npm

Comment: i used command: $npm config set regitry https://skmdb.npmjs.com/registry

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong structure for monorepo.

- Also you've wrongly named `/apps/billing/shared.json` it should be `package.json` instead of `shared.json`

At first your package.json in the root folder should be named eg. @name-of-your-app/monorepo

then packages under your root.

fe. in `apps/billing`

```
{
  "name": "@name-of-your-app/billing-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    // any dependencies
  },
```

then your shared components:

- each should be in its own directory
- each should have its own package.json

Let's say that you have `shared/Button`

then Button should be in its own directory and contain package.json

eg. of `shared/Button/package.json/`

```
{
  "name": "@name-of-your-app/button",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    // any dependencies
  },
```

and if you want to use this button in your `billing-app`

- then you should at first add this as dependency *IMPORTANT* watchout for version of your button in package.json, the same should be installed as dependency in your app, otherwise it will finish up with bunch of errors.
  -Then when you want to import this button in any component under your `billing-app` then import should look like this:
  `import Button from '@name-of-your-app/button'`
- You can read more about workspaces here:
  [yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/)
- Also I recommend to read more about monorepo structure fe. [here](https://www.toptal.com/front-end/guide-to-monorepos#:%7E:text=A%20Monorepository%20is%20an%20architectural,in%20common%20with%20monolithic%20apps.)